# SPARQL Graph Pattern comparison

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

A SPARQL  Graph Pattern is a conjunction of triple patterns of the form UBVxUVxUBVL.
Where U is URI, B is a Blank Node V is a variable and L is a Literal.

#### Example:

Query q1

```
Select ?author where
?author ex:wrote ?book
```

Query q2

```
Select ?author where
?author ex:wrote ?book
?book ex:title "Eaters of the dead"
```

What is the best algorithm to compare the two basic graph patterns?  For instance, results for the graph pattern of q2 are a subset of those for q1.  How could I programmatically determine this?

Comment: Do you care about variable names?

Comment: No, I dont care about the variable names, it about the result of the patterns in the graph

Comment: OK, and since you're saying that q2 is included in q1 (even though there's a literal value in q2 and a variable in q1), it sounds like you're looking for some kind of graph isomorphism and unification problem.  That's probably going to be expensive.  Also, you said you're concerned with "the result of the patterns in the graph".  If you mean the result set, then there's an important gap in that q1 will have bindings for `?z`, but q2 doesn't even have a variable corresponding to `?z` (and `"Eaters of the dead"` won't appear in the result set).   Can you try to pin down the relationship you're…

Comment: …looking for a bit more concretely?  You might be able to something by transforming all the literal values to variables with corresponding `values` blocks, and then compute graph isomorphism on the triple patterns, and then see whether the values for the corresponding variables are subsets of the others…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Sorry, it was my mistake. I corrected the queries. And again the question is about the result set of q2 which is included in the result set of q1.

Comment: OK, so it's not that the graph pattern is included (since q2 is actually bigger than q1), but that the *results* of q2 are a subset of the results of *q1*, because *q1* is less specific than *q2*

Comment: You don't want to _run_ the queries, right?  If you're willing to run the queries, you could do a set difference with a SPARQL query and find out whether the results of one were a subset of the other.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor of course I dont want to run the queries. The idea is to find which pattern is more specific than the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to pull off what you're trying by converting the where clause into a graph.  Then you can use standard graph algorithms to compare the queries, like using isomorphism to see if they're the same one.

Answer (score 0):

The more specific pattern should return a smaller result set if q2 is part of q1. Therefore counting the two sets and subtracting count(q2) from count (q1) will show the number of authors in q1 which are not in q2, showing that q2 is more specific. If the result is negative, then Q2 was more specific.

For example:

```
 SELECT ((?countQ1 - ?countQ2) as ?result) WHERE {

       {SELECT (count(distinct ?author) as ?countQ1) WHERE {
              ?author ex:wrote ?book .
       }}

       {SELECT (count(distinct ?author) as ?countQ2) WHERE {
              ?author ex:wrote ?book .
              ?book ex:title "Eaters of the dead"
       }}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your solution does not make difference between the two queries. The two patterns are equivalent (they have the same attributes which is "author" in the example. So the algorithm must verify this equivalence, then decide which one is more specific than the other.